# How do I submit a bug report for Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, report

I have found a number of bugs in Microsoft Office 2007, but I can't find anywhere to submit bug reports. I have seen [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) but it doesn't let me provide feedback on Office.

How do I submit a bug report for Microsoft Office?

Comment: lol does anyone else find it ironic that MS has produced a product with bugs and made it hard for you to figure out how to submit a bug report :D

Comment: I suppose, if no one ever submits bug reports to them (which is the case right now, since it is nigh on impossible to do), then they must have *a bug free product*!

Comment: There is a website for Edge bugs (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues which is FULL of bugerports), but not for Office. Is this strange? I think not. Office is of such a horrible quality and has so many bugs that Microsoft would drown in bugreports.

Comment: What is the 2020 solution to report Microsoft 365 bugs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method for regular users is to contact Microsoft Support by phone or email. If they can reproduce the issue they will create the bug report on your behalf.

Comment: It would be great if this answer includes an actual email address that can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but one answer today is to use the Feedback feature.

Press the "File" tab near the top left, and select "Feedback from the options on the left hand side.

This will take you to a Feedback application.

Answer (score 0):

I have second-hand experience of consulting Microsoft support. For, other people's support threads are available on the web and often I find that stuff when searching for a solution to the problem. What I've found is that approximately 90% of the time Microsoft support manage in no way whatsoever to solve the problem. Indeed it seems to me that most of the time the support people barely try, or at least do not try with any intelligence.

Office has long standing bugs and, unless one fancies the dialogue with the deaf that the above involves, there is nothing one can do.