# How to report an Excel bug to Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How does one report a bug in Microsoft Excel 2010?

Comment: What's the bug? I'm interested

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/26254/how-do-i-submit-a-bug-report-for-microsoft-office

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-bugs/office/) does not accept bugs for Excel.

You should [raise a support case with Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=918&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn).

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://answers.microsoft.com, the MS Office / Excel part of the forum and post a complete description of the bug there.  Include Windows version, Office version, Service Pack level if any and steps to repro the problem.

You should be able to get confirmation that it is indeed a bug, perhaps get suggestions for workarounds, and one of the Excel MVPs should be able to pass the bug along to the appropriate people at MS.